# Passing file contents rather than filename to the xlrd module's open_workbook() method

Tags: python, xlrd

Is there a way to pass the *contents* of an Excel file, rather than a file name/reference, to the xlrd module's open_workbook() function? I've been trying to use the "file_contents" parameter for this purpose, but haven't had any success with it so far. Thank you.

Comment: Hint for your next question: "haven't had any success with it so far" is not very helpful ... try showing the **code** for your best effort and the **error message** and **traceback**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most places where an open file is needed, a [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) object will also work.

You just cread a StringIO object from the file data and pass that object as the file to your function.

Comment: Thanks, Ber. I was inspecting it some more, and it turned out that what I thought was the raw binary excel file data was actually a FieldStorage object containing the excel file data, and thus, was causing an exception to be generated. Think I've got it sorted now.

Comment: why -1? open_workbook_xls allows file_contents param. check documentarion please or source code: https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/master/xlrd/book.py

Answer (score 2):

@Ber's comment is correct. You will need to use the getvalue() method of the StringIO object and pass that to the file_content parameter in the function call.

```
f = StringIO.StringIO(content)
book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents = f.getvalue() )
```